# Input of type 'Unknown' is not supported. Supported types: [azureml.data.tabular_dataset.TabularDataset, azureml.pipeline.core

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

According to this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-train-automl-client/azureml.train.automl.automlconfig.automlconfig?view=azure-ml-py

training_data can be either a dataframe or a dataset.

However when I use a dataframe I get this error:

```
ConfigException: ConfigException:
    Message: Input of type 'Unknown' is not supported. Supported types: [azureml.data.tabular_dataset.TabularDataset, azureml.pipeline.core.pipeline_output_dataset.PipelineOutputTabularDataset]
    InnerException: None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "Input of type 'Unknown' is not supported. Supported types: [azureml.data.tabular_dataset.TabularDataset, azureml.pipeline.core.pipeline_output_dataset.PipelineOutputTabularDataset]",
        "details_uri": "https://aka.ms/AutoMLConfig",
        "target": "training_data",
        "inner_error": {
            "code": "BadArgument",
            "inner_error": {
                "code": "ArgumentInvalid",
                "inner_error": {
                    "code": "InvalidInputDatatype"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code is really simple:

```
client = CosmosClient(HOST, MASTER_KEY)
database = client.get_database_client(database=DATABASE_ID)
container = database.get_container_client(CONTAINER_ID)

item_list = list(container.read_all_items(max_item_count=10))
df = pd.DataFrame(item_list)

from azureml.core.workspace import Workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config()

from azureml.automl.core.forecasting_parameters import ForecastingParameters

forecasting_parameters = ForecastingParameters(time_column_name='EventEnqueuedUtcTime', 
                                               forecast_horizon=50,
                                               time_series_id_column_names=["eui"],
                                               freq='H',
                                               target_lags='auto',
                                               target_rolling_window_size=10)

from azureml.core.workspace import Workspace
from azureml.core.experiment import Experiment
from azureml.train.automl import AutoMLConfig
from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget, AmlCompute
import logging

amlcompute_cluster_name = "computecluster"
compute_target = ComputeTarget(workspace=ws, name=amlcompute_cluster_name)
experiment_name = 'iot-forecast'

experiment = Experiment(ws, experiment_name)

automl_config = AutoMLConfig(task='forecasting',
                             primary_metric='normalized_root_mean_squared_error',
                             experiment_timeout_minutes=100,
                             enable_early_stopping=True,
                             training_data=df,
                             compute_target = compute_target,
                             label_column_name='TempC_DS',
                             n_cross_validations=5,
                             enable_ensembling=False,
                             verbosity=logging.INFO,
                             forecasting_parameters=forecasting_parameters)

remote_run = experiment.submit(automl_config, show_output=True)
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to run the experiment remotely, AFAIK and as per the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-auto-train#data-source-and-format?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003930) :

[image]

You could refer this article to understand creating [Azure ML TabularDataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-register-datasets?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003930)